# How to send email notifications for the same Jenkins job in one email thread

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, email-ext

I am using Jenkins Email-ext plugin to send email notifications when the job starts and in the end (if the job succeeded). And I want those notifications to be part of one email thread (not separate emails with the same subject).

I looked through all settings in global Jenkins config and experimented with different options of Editable Email Notification in Post Build section. No luck so far.

There is a feature request for Email-ext plugin to add "In-Reply-To" filed which, according to the request's description, should make it possible to see emails for the same job in one thread.
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-3089
The feature is implemented but I can't find this field anywhere. I am using the latest version of the plugin (for now 2.40.5)

Answer (score 0):

The In-Reply-To gets added automatically by the plugin, it is not configurable.